# Back from a form to a particular tab - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Form having tabs

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
tabs.addTab("Events", wrapContainerSingleTable);
tabs.addTab("Business Meetings", wrapContainerSingleTableMeeting);

Button addEventButton = new Button("Add Event ");
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(addEventButton, FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD);
wrapContainerSingleTable.add(FlowLayout.encloseRight(addEventButton));

addEventButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
    showForm("AddEvent", null);
});

Button addMeetingButton = new Button("Add Meeting ");
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(addMeetingButton, FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD);
wrapContainerSingleTableMeeting.add(FlowLayout.encloseRight(addMeetingButton));

addMeetingButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
    showForm("AddMeeting", null);
});
```

back in addEvent and addMeeting form:

```
Command back = new Command("Back", backBtn) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        showForm("MeetingsAndEvents", this);
    }

};
back.putClientProperty("uiid", "RoundTableBack");
f.setBackCommand(back);
t.addCommandToLeftBar(back);
```

What I need here is that when I go back from add event, it should go to events tab and likewise when I go back from add meeting tab, it should go to meeting tab. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using setSelectedIndex() on your Tabs component in your actionPerformed() methods.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your state machine:

```
protected void storeComponentState(Component c, Hashtable destination) {
   super.storeComponentState(c, destination);
   if(c instanceof Tabs) {
        destination.put("TabSel" + c.getName(), ((Tabs)c).getSelectedIndex());
   }
}

protected void restoreComponentState(Component c, Hashtable destination) {
   super.restoreComponentState(c, destination);
   if(c instanceof Tabs) {
        Integer i = (Integer)destination.get("TabSel" + c.getName());
        if(i != null) {
           ((Tabs)c).setSelectedIndex(i.intValue());
        }
   }
}
```